# MySQL - Column counting function positional errors

Tags: mysql, function

Im trying to make a function which returns a valued integer

(based on the amount of indexes within a table called BOOKCAT)

first im trying to load the table to make sure it runs but, i keep receiving an error saying the delimiter is not a valid position

(this is my experience with functions)

.Ref is a foreign key used to identify the number of cat IDs kept in a booking

results of this table look like the following:

```
BOOKCAT
Ref CatID
'1', '1'
'2', '2'
'2', '3'
'3', '1'
'4', '2'
'5', '3'
'5', '4'
'6', '5'
'7', '6'
'7', '7'
'7', '8'
```

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION Calc(ReferenceNumber INTEGER)
RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN 
DECLARE NUMCATS INTEGER;
    SELECT SUM(BOOKCAT.Ref = ReferenceNumber)
    FROM BOOKCAT;

    SET NUMCATS = SUM(BOOKCAT.Ref = ReferenceNumber);

    RETURN NUMCATS;
END|
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Perhaps you don't need to set delimiters - what ide are you using to create this function if none then how. Also you need to SET variables and you cannot return a result set in a function What is the select supposed to do? AND what is FROK BOOKCAT? I suggest you have another go at this..

Comment: MySQL workbench - mac, ive updated the question and code, BOOKCAT is the table,  the positional error is still persistent, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The set statement is just wrong without a select - it has no notion of bookcat. simplest change is to select into and you should space before the delimiters. Also if ref and catid are integers you don't need to quote the insert values.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(Ref int, CatID int);
insert into t values
(1,1),
(2,2),
(2,3),
(3,1),
(4,2),
(5,3),
(5,4),
(6,5),
(7,6),
(7,7),
(7,8);

drop function if exists f;
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION f(ReferenceNumber INTEGER)
RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN 
DECLARE NUMCATS INTEGER;
    SELECT SUM(BOOKCAT.Ref = ReferenceNumber) into numcats
    FROM t bookcat;

    #SET NUMCATS = SUM(BOOKCAT.Ref = ReferenceNumber);

    RETURN NUMCATS;
END |
DELIMITER ;

select f(7);

+------+
| f(7) |
+------+
|    3 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```